# Programmatic interface for CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I plan on developing a CasperJS component which will be part of a larger system.

The CasperJS component will need to have a programmatic interface so that I can pass in data to be used and retrieve results.

I see that PhantomJS has a WebServer module. Is it possible to implement a REST API with that module?

I see that the WebServer module only handles something like 10 concurrent requests. Can I increase this or create some kind of multi process load balanced solution for higher throughput.

EDIT :: Apologies for the broad question. More specifically, how can I implement a REST API to communicate with CasperJS?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Your question seems like it's too broad though.

Comment: Updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Even with the update this is still a very broad question—you can accomplish this in a number of ways. To your point, you could stick a load balancer in front of multiple instances. As for the API part, you can write it as you normally would.

Comment: Well I don't know how to do either. To be honest, in programming/CS in general. Everything can be done in a multitude. Why don't you pick JUST one way and answer..?

Comment: @conor [this repo](https://github.com/whymarrh/phantomjs-server) of mine is a crude example of how a server could be implemented

Comment: @Whymarrh Cool, thanks. Just the job :)